# Angular push and splice array elements bound to html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I have a little form like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxZd9.png) whenever I click "add" a new row gets added.

HTML:

```
   <div class="tel" *ngFor="let t of tel; let i = index">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.telFijo" [name]="'tfijo'+i">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.telCelular" [name]="'tcel' + i">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.anexo" [name]="'anex' + i">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.skype" [name]="'skype' + i">
            </div>
            <div id="em" class="col-md-3">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.email" [name]="'email' + i">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <i id="trash" class="fa fa-trash" (click)="eliminar(i)"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Whenever I add I push an object.

```
  agregar() {
 const telefono = new Telefono();
this.tel.push(telefono);
}
```

And whenever I remove an item I splice it in the current position.

```
 eliminar(i) {
 this.tel.splice(i, 1);
 }
```

That works fine, the issue is that when I try to add a new row after I deleted one, the last two rows get deleted.

[In this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs6ta.png) I had 3 rows, deleted the middle one and then added one. Which made the previous one get deleted. I honestly have no idea why this happens. I would love to know if there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition

```
agregar() {
  const telefono = new Telefono();
  this.tel.push(telefono);
}
```

Comment: I had telefono as a global variable that was also a new Telefono(); and it didn't work, just for clarification declaring it inside the method is also not working :/